# Inheritance from Controller in Asp.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inheritance, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-controller

I created a generic controller class

```
namespace OxygenFramework.MvcController
{
  public class MvcController<TEntity> : Controller
    where TEntity : class
  {
    public void UpdateModelState(TEntity t)
    {
        ...
    }
  }
}
```

then I used it as below

```
namespace LeitnerMVC.Controllers
  {
    public class HomeController : MvcController<Account>
     {
    //
    // GET: /Home/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        UpdateModelState(t);
        return View();
    }
  }
}
```

BUT when run mvc application page shows this error

```
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies)     could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
```

after searched in web I found a way for solve it

```
  void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                 
    ControllerBuilder.Current.DefaultNamespaces.Add("OxygenFramework.MvcController");
    }
```

**But above solution does not work for me !!! and shows Http 404 error again**

**When use Controller instead of MvcController page shows without problem !!!**

Can anyone help me ?

**Update :**

after many investigation I understand why this problem occurs but still I dont know how resolve that.
WHEN I move source code of MvcController out of my framework assemby (OxygenFramework.MvcController) and move it into MVC project MvcController works but when I refrence MvcController from OxygenFramework assembly MVC shows 404 error !!!
Now I know this problem occur because MvcController is into another assembly
but I dont know how solve this problem

**attention :** only generic implimentation of MvcController is in OxygenFramework assembly
and all of Controller is into the default Controllers folder

Comment: 1. what page (url) shows you 404? 2. What web engine do you use? 3. Is HomeController located in Controllers folder?

Comment: 1. http://localhost/Home/Index      2. MVC (Razor)    3. Yes

Comment: Add "LeitnerMVC.Controllers" to the default namespaces.

Comment: I added it but did not work !!! :(

Comment: What's about files locations? (the controllers and Account ones)

Comment: All Controllers in default Controllers folder - Account is my DTO in separated Assembly

Comment: "When use Controller instead of MvcController page shows without problem", just to clarify... That means if you inherit HomeController from Controller -- that's ok, but when from MvcController -- not ok? (As generally, everything works for me in any way).

Comment: (I would also do the MvcController class as 'abstract').

Comment: not works :( I added abstract but did not work , yes when I inherit from controller works but with MvcController does not work ! I don't know why ?!!!!!!!

Comment: Oh, as for "abstract" -- that was just general thought. (Not related to this very problem). As for the problem -- you need to provide either the progect(s) all together(at least basic points) or more code, as basicly it works for me (and must work conceptually). So, if you want, you can get into chat and provide some link with the project etc.

Comment: @Agat  thanks for your help I updated my post please see that, yes code works in Mvc Solution but when I referenced MvcController from my framework assembly it does not works and shows 404 error. Are you any idea ?

Comment: Are you sure that that separate assembly is included into output folder of main project?

Comment: *(I meant 'bin' folder, of course).

Comment: I have an Assembly as my library (framework) , assembly name is OxygenFramework so into this assembly I created some classes for some problems such as validation, repository pattern , ... and Generic implementation of MvcController (above code) then I created a Mvc Application and add referenced OxygenFramework assembly and inherited from it when I inherit from this referenced assembly mvc shows 404 error but when I move source into simple class in MvcApplication shows correctly

Comment: Yes. I got the way you use that in development (as you would not be able to inherit from parent class), but I can not locate the cause of the problem -- for me, the basic implementation of the situation works well. So, I can only suggest you to provide 'lite' version of your code for closer look by me somehow.

Comment: @Agat Dear Agat I found problem and solved it !!! I used System.Web.Mvc.dll version 4.0 in my framework but used System.Web.Mvc.dll 5.0 in my MvcApplication ! :D

Comment: Aha. That's weird that you even was able to compile the project (if you really was), so I was considering you've done with all such corrections already.

Comment: Anyway, you should write an answer on your question in any case, if you solved the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After many investigation I found problem
I want to say @Agat thank you :)

But Solution : 
I used System.Web.Mvc.dll version 4.0 in my framework but used System.Web.Mvc.dll 5.0 in my MvcApplication !
This interference causes the 404 error from inheritance :D